# How to run multiple Django sites on Nginx and uWSGI?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

Is it possible to run multiple Django sites on the same server using Nginx and uWSGI?

I suppose it's necessary to run multiple uWSGI instances (one for each site). I copied /etc/init.d/uwsgi to uwsgi2 and changed the port number. But, I got the following error:

```
# /etc/init.d/uwsgi2 start
Starting uwsgi: /usr/bin/uwsgi already running.
```

How is it possible to run multiple uWSGI instances?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is the same question at serverfault, 
http://serverfault.com/questions/498994/how-to-run-multiple-websites-from-one-django-project-on-nginx-and-uwsgi/549337#549337

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create create multiple virtual hosts that allow you to host multiple sites, independent from each other. More info here: http://wiki.nginx.org/VirtualHostExample.

A bit more detailed info here as well on how to setup virtual hosts http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/RunOnNginx#VirtualHosting.

Comment: The solution to run 2 uwsgi instances was in the second link:

uwsgi --uid 1001 -w customer1app --limit-as 128 -p 3 -M -s 127.0.0.1:3031

Comment: If you run uwsgi in Emperor mode it'll handle the creation of multiple instances (aka vassals). You just need a uwsgi config file for each django project. More info: https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#emperor-mode

Comment: Both links are outdated.

Answer (score 5):

You can run multiple instances of uwsgi using [Emperor Mode](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#emperor-mode).

This handles the creation of new worker instances. These instances are brilliantly and hilariously named [vassals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vassal). Each vassal just needs a config file which is usually placed (or symlinked) in `/etc/uwsgi/vassals`

For nginx you'll need to create a server block for each host you wish to serve. Just change the `server_name` directive for each host you want to serve. Here's an example:

```
#Simple HTTP server
server {
    listen   80; 
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    server_name host1.example.com;
}

#Django server
server {
    listen   80; 
    server_name host2.example.com;

    #...upstream config...
}
```

**Important:** Make sure you have specified your host names in `/etc/hosts`. I found that without doing this my django site was also served on the default server IP despite specifying that it should only be served on a specific host name within my nginx configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I see many suggestions like @donturner's answer. i.e. set two or more different `server` in nginx configure file. But the problem is each server needs an unique `server_name` either different domain name or sub-domain name. How about this kind of situation: I want to server two different Django project like this:

```
www.ourlab.cn/site1/  # first Django project
www.ourlab.cn/site2/  # second Django project
```

In this way, we can configure all of the settings **in one server**.

This is my setting in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

}
```

This is my setting in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/self_configure.conf`

```
# /etc/nginx/conf.d/self_configure.conf
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.ourlab.cn;

    # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
    root   /mnt/data/www/ourlab;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        # your Django project's media files - amend as required
        alias /mnt/data/www/metCCS/metCCS/static/media;
    }

    location /static {
        # your Django project's static files - amend as required
        # first project's static files path
        alias /mnt/data/www/metCCS/metCCS/static/static_dirs;
    }
    location /static_lip {
        # second project's static files path
        alias /mnt/data/www/lipidCCS/lipidCCS/static/static_dirs;
    }

    # match www.ourlab.cn/metccs/*
    location ~* ^/metccs {
        include     uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass  unix:/run/uwsgi/metCCS.sock;
    }
    # match www.ourlab.cn/lipidccs/*
    location ~* ^/lipidccs {
        include     uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass  unix:/run/uwsgi/lipidCCS.sock;
    }
}
```

You also need to change one of the Django project's `settings.py` file as `STATIC_URL = '/static_lip/'`, so two projects can use their static files separately.

A new finding is `nginx` can server static files by itself. Even we close uwsgi and Django, we also can use these files through browser.